# Drawing two shapes with transparency in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, paint, android-view

I'm drawing two shapes in Android using paint and canvas. I applied transparency to the paint color, but now when the two shapes (same color) intersect the intersecting section comes out darker.

[image]

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Here is a quick look at my paint code (which... should be the only object necessary to complete this I imagine).

```
        Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(color);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
paint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(15));
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
```

Comment: This is a hack, but you could fill the left circle, fill the right circle with the background color and then fill the right circle with the same color as the left circle

Comment: The problem is that it's not a solid color... but actually a transparent color.

Comment: I understand that, but try drawing the first shape, drawing the second shape with white(or whatever your background color is) as the color, and then drawing the second shape again with the correct color.

Comment: Ah. Gotcha. A little hacky... but it could work. Though I am using a background image... which doesn't allow this to work.