# Android Custom View doesn't handle transparency/alpha the right way

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, alpha

I'm drawing a custom view. In this view I use two different paint and path objects to paint to the canvas. I'm basically drawing two shapes that overlap. After I add alpha, the part of the view that is overlapped is darker than the rest of the image. This is undesired, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

This is a clipping of my code to show how I'm using alpha in my NewButtonView.java

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
int color = 0x33ffffff;
int borderColor = 0xFF000000;

paint.setColor(color);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
```

About 31 minutes into this [Google I/O video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQZFaec9NpA#t=1860)... they show my desired effect.

They basically show this image:
[image]

Add transparency and get this image: UNDESIRED RESULT

[image]

They end up with this: DESIRED RESULT

[image]

Does anyone have any idea on how to get this desired affect?

Comment: are you sure it is the alpha that you want to change? seems like your desired effect has zero transparency still, it is just lightened.

Comment: Yes, I need transparency because I am using a textured background that has to be seen.

Comment: My best thought then is to see if there is a way to draw the overlapping shapes as one shape (or combine them as one after they are drawn). Adding alpha to the composite shape should result they way you want

Comment: Yeah, its just that I'm drawing two circles, overlapping each other, and drawing that type of "binocular shape" seems unnecessary when I can just draw two circles.

Comment: In the video, they mentioned `Canvas.saveLayerAlpha()` method. Did you try to use it?

Comment: I might be barking up the wrong tree, but shouldn't you be setting the alpha on the container rather than the buttons?

Comment: @EGHDK Just saw another one of your questions: [Drawing two shapes with transparency in Android/Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009242/drawing-two-shapes-with-transparency-in-android-java). If you had explained your actual problem in detail, or linked to this question in your post, I could have given you a better solution. In any case, good luck.

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned in the video, you would use `Canvas#saveLayerAlpha(....)` for this. You can also get a similar effect without using it. I'll discuss that later on.

Let's create a sample view:

```
public class SampleView extends View {

    // Declare Paint objects
    Paint paintColor, paintBorder;

    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Initialize and set up Paint objects
        paintColor = new Paint();
        paintBorder = new Paint();

        paintColor.setAntiAlias(true);
        paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);

        paintBorder.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paintBorder.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paintBorder.setStrokeWidth(10);

        // Just a random image to 'see' the difference
        setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hor_lines));
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        // Save layer alpha for Rect that covers the view : alpha is 90 / 255
        canvas.saveLayerAlpha(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 90, 
                                             Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);

        // Draw first circle, and then the border
        paintColor.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 3, getHeight() / 2, 
                                           getWidth() / 4 - 20, paintColor);

        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 3, getHeight() / 2, 
                                           getWidth() / 4 - 15, paintBorder);

        // Draw second circle, and then the border
        paintColor.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(2 * getWidth() / 3, getHeight() / 2, 
                                           getWidth() / 4 - 20, paintColor);
        canvas.drawCircle(2 * getWidth() / 3, getHeight() / 2, 
                                           getWidth() / 4 - 15, paintBorder);

        // Finally, restore the canvas
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

What happens:

1. An off-screen bitmap is allocated when `saveLayerAlpha(....)` is called.
2. All drawing operations happen on this bitmap.
3. When `canvas.restore()` is called, this bitmap is transferred to the on-screen canvas, and the alpha value we supplied in `saveLayerAlpha(....)` is applied to the off-screen bitmap.

(I think) The following is an equivalent way of creating this effect without using `saveLayerAlpha(....)`:

```
public class SView extends View {

    Paint paintColor, paintBorder, paintAlpha;

    Bitmap toDrawOn;

    public SView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        paintAlpha = new Paint();

        paintAlpha.setColor(Color.parseColor("#90FFFFFF"));
        paintAlpha.setAntiAlias(true);

        ....
        ....

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (toDrawOn == null) {

            // Create a new Bitmap
            toDrawOn = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), 
                                                    Config.ARGB_8888);

            // Create a new Canvas; drawing operations 
            // will happen on 'toDrawOn'
            Canvas offScreen = new Canvas(toDrawOn);

            // First circle
            paintColor.setColor(Color.RED);
            offScreenCanvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 3, getHeight() / 2, 
                                           getWidth() / 4 - 20, paintColor);
            offScreenCanvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 3, getHeight() / 2, 
                                           getWidth() / 4 - 15, paintBorder);

            // Second circle
            paintColor.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            offScreenCanvas.drawCircle(2 * getWidth() / 3, getHeight() / 2, 
                                           getWidth() / 4 - 20, paintColor);
            offScreenCanvas.drawCircle(2 * getWidth() / 3, getHeight() / 2, 
                                           getWidth() / 4 - 15, paintBorder);

            // Draw bitmap 'toDrawOn' to canvas using 'paintAlpha'
            canvas.drawBitmap(toDrawOn, 0, 0, paintAlpha);

        } else {

            // 'toDrawOn' is not null; draw it
            canvas.drawBitmap(toDrawOn, 0, 0, paintAlpha);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Just for reference, the base container in the image above is a `LinearLayout` with background set to this jpeg: [Link](http://images1.pixlis.com/background-image-horizontal-lines-and-stripes-seamless-tileable-black-white-22h8w7.png).

And, the drawable used as the background of SampleView:

```
// Just a random image to 'see' the difference
setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hor_lines));
```

is taken from: [here](http://tutorialphotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Horizontal-Lines.jpg).

Comment: Also you can create a cavanas draw images with 100% opacity and then reduce the cavanas opacity.

Comment: @MarcosEusebi How will you change the transparency/opacity of a canvas?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mind that. Join images into a bitmap then draw the bitmap to the cavnas and set the opacity of the bitmap.

Comment: Note that docs recommend using hardware layer for a View rather than saveLayer* methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw everything in a bitmap with full alpha, and then change the bitmap's alpha

(Sorry, this is more a comment than an answer but stack overflow won't allow me to post comments)